# Representing inheritance in an Entity Relational to Relational Mapping diagram

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database, database-schema, entity-relationship

I have an Entity Relational Diagram for a library management system. I have the entities "Member" and "Professor", and "Professor" inherits attributes from "Member".

Then I have my ER to relational mapping diagram and here is the issue I am facing - how to represent the connection between "Member" and "Professor"?[image]

[image]

Here are the diagrams, as you can see there is no Professor added to the 2nd diagram. Any tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtypes normally use the same primary key as the supertype, and record any additional attributes.  In your example, `Professor` has no additional attributes besides the `SSN` that identifies it as a `Member`.  So, in your relational diagram you would draw a `Professors` table with a single column - `Member_SSN` - which points back to the `SSN` column of `Members`.